# Maven 2 is Still Alive : Even after setting Maven3

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

And i got a requirement, converting a `Maven 2` project to `Maven 3`. So i downloaded Maven 3.2.1 and edited the Maven path to 3.And also changed Maven installation in eclipse to point Maven 3.

But when i run my project in eclipse, it is still taking maven 2 plugins. Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: What do you mean by maven 2 plugin? Can you give examples for that? I assume your plugins have been defined by a pluginManagement block?

Answer (score 0):

Versions are just versions, there's no real relation between the Maven version and the plugin version. Actually, the Maven team tried to keep the maven-plugins as much as possible compatible with Maven3. 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Plugin+Compatibility+Matrix shows the list of maven plugins and from which version they can be used with Maven3. Only the Maven-site-plugin required a major release, since it had to adopt the reporting part which has been removed with Maven3.